# how i can give background color and any transition to a full column of table on hover in css?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm getting problem to give a color and transition on hover to a full column.

I tried this to increase my expertise level. I hope someone will give answer of it

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover effect on which element do you want (here that is column )

```
.column:hover {
   color: red;
 }
```

for transition firstly give transition property to column and add time like this

```
.column{transition : all 2s;}
```